# How to write a query that uses time attrition (e.g. within 1 day, within 2 days)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I 2 tables:
Enable
Disable

Each of those tables are tied to DateId to a date table that stores their dates.

How would I write a query so I can get rows in the disable table that disabled within 1, 2 or 3 days of having an entry in the enable table?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you can include the schema of your database tables we will be able to give you more help.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)! It works really well, and returns you the difference in dates.

```
select
    *
from
    disable d
    inner join enable e on
        d.Id = e.Id
where
    datediff(day, e.DateId, d.DateId) between 1 and 3
```

You can also use it for any difference you'd like. `DATEDIFF` can also go backwards, so you could do `datediff(day, d.DateId, e.DateId) between -3 and -1`, if that struck your fancy.